# WSO2 EMM: Error past device authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I run the WSO2 EMM Agent on an Android device

After entering username and password on the agent, clicking **Register**  and selecting **Yes** on **Your device is a COPE device, are you sure you want to proceed?** I get the error *Connection Failed, Server is unavailable. Please contact administrator.*

Server running Linux 2.6 and Java version 1.7.0_79-b15.

Here is the exception:

> [2015-05-27 16:57:59,693] ERROR
>   {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
>   - org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "trim" of null (/emm/modules/device.js#1140)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "trim"
>   of null (/emm/modules/device.js#1140) at
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "trim"
>   of null (/emm/modules/device.js#1140) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3731)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2258)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2251)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:83)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c6._c_anonymous_38(/emm/modules/device.js:1140)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c6.call(/emm/modules/device.js) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.api.c4._c_anonymous_10(/emm/api/deviceRouter.js:115)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.api.c4.call(/emm/api/deviceRouter.js) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c5._c_anonymous_13(/emm/modules/goose.js:174)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c5.call(/emm/modules/goose.js) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3._c_callAPI_12(/emm/modules/absolute.js:171)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3.call(/emm/modules/absolute.js)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
>   at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3._c_anonymous_15(/emm/modules/absolute.js:228)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c3.call(/emm/modules/absolute.js)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.c0._c_script_0(/emm//index.jag:189) at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.c0.call(/emm//index.jag) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>   at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.c0.call(/emm//index.jag) at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.c0.exec(/emm//index.jag) at
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>   ... 73 more

Does anyone here know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following answer by me[1] and see whether you have enrolled your device properly.

[1] - [WSO2 EMM: Error past device authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495294/wso2-emm-error-past-device-authentication/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, your link points back to this same question.

Comment: Looks like you have an issue generating Client ID and secret. Can you get a fresh EMM pack and check this again? Start with "sh ./wso2server.sh -Dsetup" command.